# Random object generator c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, random

I've been working on a project that is supposed to recreate the tripulation of a plane. 
I couldn't figure out how to program a key feature that I want it to have.

How can I generate a set number of objects that pick their parameters from a predefined list? For example, suppose we have the class "Passenger" which takes the parameters Name, Age, Nationality and phoneNumber. I need the program to generate, let's say 10 objects of the class passenger and take their attributes randomly from an array of 20 preset names. I know I could define 10 objects by myself, but what happens if I want to generate like 100 of them? Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a vector that contains the specified number of objects and then use a for loop to dynamically create and insert Passenger objects into that vector. For random properties, just get a random number the same size as your predefined lists and get the element at that index.